# How to Safely Copy Entire Ubuntu Root Directory to Different Drive and use it as system drive via SSH?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, rsync, fstab

I'm currently maintaining a remote Ubuntu server with two drives: one SSD and one HDD. The HDD is currently mounted at /, serving as the system drive, while the SSD is empty and mounted at /mnt/nvme. I need to switch them so that the SSD becomes the system drive and the HDD is used for data storage only.

Here's what I've attempted so far:

1. Copy root to SSD:
   `rsync -axHAWXS --numeric-ids --info=progress2 / /mnt/nvme`
2. Edit the fstab file so that the UUID of the mountpoint / points to the SSD drive.
3. Reboot the system.

My edited fstab file looks like this:

```
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=167cc84d-edf2-4835-91ec-7a3b070fc8ee /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=20dfd0dd-196e-4cef-947a-87447692aeca /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
#UUID=167cc84d-edf2-4835-91ec-7a3b070fc8ee /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=B1E7-121D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
UUID=CCDC-B53F  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

so first UUID is pointing to SSD drive and second for HDD (the same with `boot/efi`).
But after rebooting it doesnt work, hdd drive is still mounted at / where ssd is umounted.

My guess is this is because copying data from root wasnt perfect, some dirs couldn't be copied even as root user, i checked those dirs permission and they were weird like this `d????????? ? ? ? ? ? gvfs`. So right now i'm stuck and wonder what should i try next.

I'm seeking advice on how to resolve this issue. Is there a workaround to copy all files successfully, even when encountering such permission errors? Alternatively, I'm considering installing a new Ubuntu OS on the SSD drive by downloading the ISO and attempting to install it remotely using only the terminal. Can anyone confirm if this approach is feasible?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: What you call a "*system drive*" is also probably the device for the root filesystem. The device/partition for the rootfs is specified to the Linux kernel when it boots using the kernel command line. Editing the **fstab** file cannot be the solution because that file is in the rootfs. The specification is in the same filesystem, so you have a chicken & egg problem. The boot parameters you need to edit are used by the bootloader, e,g, grub or U-Boot.

Comment: Do not copy a rootfs while mounted. Instead boot from a Live image on a CD, DVD, or USB drive.

Comment: @sawdust Does it mean there is no way to do this completely remotely? I was hoping to achieve this without booting a live image because this server is thousands of kilometers away from me.